Maximum number of possible edges in a graph with given conditions
We know that the maximum number of possible edges in an undirected simple graph with $n$ vertices and $k$ connected components is $\frac{(n-k)(n-k+1)}{2}$.
My query:
What would be the answer if I dropped the term "simple" from the above statement?
Can we still find the maximum number of possible edges in an undirected graph with $n$ vertices and $k$ connected components?
To me, it seems impossible as there may be so many loops and multiple edges. So, I think the statement is absurd.
Am I right in thinking so? Kindly help. Thanks for the help.

Your thinking is correct. Take any simple graph, pick a vertex and add as many loops as you want. The number of edges is now unbounded, so there is no maximum.
